# iPhone performSelector changes object type

Tags: iphone, nsstring, callback, nsdictionary

I have a callback class with the method `-(void)fire` and it calls
`[target performSelector:selector withObject:dictionary];`
Just before that line I added `NSLog(@"%@", [[dictionary class] description]);` to see where the object changed, when debugging it returns NSCFDictionary.

So that was all fine. Next I went and added a similar line to get the arguments type inside the method being called. Now, when debugging, it returns  NSCFString, whilst the callback logs NSCFDictionary.

Is there any reason why this object is becoming an NSString once I call performSelector?

Comment: What is the method signature for the method that is being called by your selector?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: @selector(TokenHandler:TokenData:)?

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one argument to your method if you use performSelector:withObject:.

Check out performSelector:withObject:withObject: or use NSInvocation.

Comment: Oh, actually, I do apologise, I haven't got my code near me. The actual selector is assigned using @selector(TokenHandler:)

Comment: And the first parameter has type (NSDictionary*)? But inside the method the object identifies itself as an NSString?

Comment: It is actually (id), but yes it is identified as NSString. I just thought and it can probably become (NSDictionary *), though it would be nice to know why it is doing this and to keep it as (id)

Comment: id is fine, I was just curious. I think you are going to have to post more of your code. I agree that your problem is very odd.